# HTML5 tag name conventions - custom tags and use of dashes

Tags: html, naming-conventions

I stumbled recently came across [this comment on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/1khhif/brick_by_mozilla_ui_components_for_modern_web_apps/cbp0597?context=2) about the naming conventions for tags on HTML. The concept of standard tags having no dashes, and custom ones having dashes, is also repeated further down the comments section - though neither commenter provides a source for this claim.

I've looked through the specification for [HTML syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html) and the [W3C's introduction to web components](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/), and though I've found the definition that custom elements must contain a hyphen [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/#defining-a-custom-element), I can't find anything to imply that standard elements *can't* contain hyphens.

Is anyone aware of an authoritative source for this, preferably from the W3C? Or is it the case that this is an unwritten rule?

Answer (score 2):

The list of standard names is known and finite. There are some standard element names, from SVG and MathML, that do contain hyphens. They are:

- annotation-xml
- color-profile
- font-face
- font-face-src
- font-face-uri
- font-face-format
- font-face-name
- missing-glyph

See the list here: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/custom/index.html#dfn-custom-element. The names are barred from being used as custom elements.

When new names are created in HTML, SVG, and MathML in the future, the choice will need to take the presence of custom elements into account to avoid collisions, but there's no point in having a spec that creates a must rule of the format of standard element names, because a later spec will simply supersede that requirement if it finds it useful to do so.